# How to send user defined data types to asmx web service from android application?

Tags: android, .net, web-services, asmx

I want to pass a user defined data type(a complex data type- an object say) to asmx web service from my android app. I have tried of sending primitive data

types and works fine. When I am trying to send the object it self as it is then I got the following error.  (See link below)

http://pastie.org/5935960

and here is the code I am using to call the web service  http://pastie.org/5936733

and this is my class Implementation http://pastie.org/5936414 and

another class implementation is here  http://pastie.org/5936586.

Note: Every thing works fine when I send the data with primitive data types but when I send the data with my class object it is throwing an exception.

Please any onc could try to tell me what may be the problem. I was on this problem for last 4 days but could not resolve it still.

Thanks 
Ganesh

Comment: You have posted too much code. You should pick the most important bits and include as embedded snippets and not link to another page.

Comment: yes but to know the exactly what I am doing and pasting the code here is causing to see a lengthy and let my query be simple and people can see the whole code in another link without any horizontal scrolling. @conor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to serialize/write your data so that it can be parsed and converted back to objects on the receiving side (asmx web service).

Popular approaches are to use JSON/XML for text based solutions i.e. human readable. There are also solutions for serializing the data to binary. I only have experience with Google protocol buffers, which worked quite well for me.

For the JSON approach you basically have a read and write method in each class you wish to transfer. These methods are used to convert your object to and from your desired format (JSON/XML).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have done that part also but the error is still persists       Object  json;
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  json= gson.toJson(thisitm); but this does not works  I added external jar files to my library. @conor